# HOW CILKPLUS divides a task among different cores of cpu

Tags: java

I was looking a bit in `cilkplus` programming. Can anyone tell me how `cilkplus` or `opencl` divides the given task to different cores of cpu.

Does `cilkpul` compiler divide the task or does it leave it to the operating system to divide it?

Answer (score 0):

"*Intel Cilk Plus uses a randomized work-stealing scheduler to perform dynamic load-balancing*".

From the [FAQ](http://cilkplus.org/faq).

You might also want to read the "*What do you mean by "dynamic load-balancing"?*" section.